# How to change received Caller Id in the FreeSwitch?

Tags: freeswitch

Our SIP Trunk provider send the caller id format inconsistently, for example:

```
628123456789
2112344445
```

62 is the Indonesia country code
81 is mobile code
21 is area code

so sometimes they send without the country code, how to automatically strip the '62' and add '0' as the prefix if it finds the '62' in the caller id? and how to just add '0' if it finds other than '62'

in my case and my expectation:

628123456789 --> 62 would be stripped and '0' would be added as prefix, so it would become 08123456789
and
2112344445 --> '0' would be added as prefix and so it would become 02112344445

any body can give me an advise?

many thanks
Dev